# Not able to use "{" and "}" characters in mongodb console

Tags: mongodb, windows-7

I am trying to use curly braces in mongodb native console client on Windows 7 but i am not able to write curly braces if i am even copy paste curly braces to console it just remove curly braces.

Which settings of console can cause this ?

Here is client console session

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.0-pr
connecting to: test
>
```

I am using 2.1.0 pre alpha version

Comment: can you please copy/paste one console session here?

Comment: @milan - Are you asking client console session or mongod.exe console ?

Comment: a client console session. pre alpha? well, try a stable release.

Comment: 2.0 stable, any stable release  :)

Comment: I have not seen this issue in 2.1.0-pre- .  What language and keyboard layout are you using?  Can you try a non-nightly release and see if it behaves the same?  There is no special handling of left and right braces by the shell, they show up in input and are displayed on the screen in normal ASCII, but perhaps a non-English keyboard or display setting could affect them.

Comment: Also, is this a version you downloaded or one you built yourself?  If it is a downloaded nightly build, can you run mongod.exe and post the Git version (SHA-1) from the build, please?

Comment: @user908088 - I am using pre-alpha version just because new aggregation framework features.

Comment: @TadMarshall - I downloaded it from MongoDB offical website in unstable nightly build secion and git version is "git version: 9c8dd2f5248c223a909f98b9c573bb112034c04d". I am using Turkish Q keyboard but i had not meet this problem on v2.0

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Your build is almost identical to what I run, so I need to try setting a different keyboard.  The Wikipedia article on keyboard layouts shows a Turkish Q keyboard ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Turkish_.28Q-keyboard.29 ) and it looks like "{" is AltGr+7 and "}" is AltGr+0 ... is this right?  So I should be able to get this effect on a US keyboard by setting Windows to use the Turkish Q layout, is that right?  If I'm on the right track, I think I just need to respect the AltGr key and not treat it as Right Alt.  Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Yes, shortcuts are right. I think you should be get same effect on if you change layout to Turkish Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the 2.1.0-pre- version, now fixed because of your report.  Thank you!  See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4611 for the writeup and a link to the change, and try a nightly build that includes the fix once one is available.  It should work correctly now.