# Cannot write brace in mongo shell (MeteorJS)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, console, server

I'm encountering an error with Meteor. So I'm following the given example and try to understand [Collections](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections).
So when it's said to execute this command line in the mongo console (another one) after doing **meteor mongo** :

> db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });

My console replace every **{** and **}** by nothing and after execution I get :

> 2016-02-02T21:57:28.699+0100 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

With two audio signals.

So, this is normal because instead having :

> db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });

I'm getting :

> db.tasks.insert( text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() );

There is another same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695400/not-able-to-use-and-characters-in-mongodb-console) which is apparently now fixed but not completely.

I would like to know why my console is doing this, so I opened an [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6142) on Meteor but they redirect me to open an issue here. It seems the console isn't working properly but how do I know it ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you are confusing things here. If you want to understand MongoDB, use the `mongo` shell first and some sort of a client (which tends to connect to the port directly). Anticipating a "But I want to learn meteor, too": Learn to walk before you run.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you in the fact I have to learn MongoDB, but my question is more "Why the given example isn't working on my computer and they don't encounter such issue".

Doing the same things as they did and not getting the same result as they got is more my interrogation right now.

But I'll check the real mongo shell first, thanks.

Comment: You are mixing concepts. Your example perfectly works in my `mongo` shell (the one you open on the command line). ;)

Comment: Nice but not with me with the same mongo shell..

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pastxubq9zgjt0b/Screenshot%202016-02-03%2010.38.19.png?dl=0

Comment: Works perfectly fine on Mac. Results with `WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })`

Comment: Well, I'll try to make it work. Thanks for your responses.